# Need help with Modular Blower to Heat Pump condenser connection

Tags: wiring

Need help here with how to connect Modular Blower, American Standard P0V0B000M40SBAA to the condenser Trane 4TRW4048G10000AC. On the modular there are O, Y1, Y2, B/C, G, R, W1, W2 AND BK. The condenser side, there are X2, Y, O, O, R, Y0, B and B. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide us with links to the service manuals or photos of the wiring diagrams for the units in question please?

Comment: Newbie here and not sure how pictures, images can be attached in this

Comment: Just found the link to the HP Condenser: https://www.trane.com/content/dam/Trane/Commercial/global/products-systems/equipment/unitary/split-systems/Small%20Splits/Air%20Conditioners/22-1765-13H-EN_10252019.PDF